# Can we call Azure API Management through c# code without using SAS Token

Tags: c#, .net, azure, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have configured oauth2.0 authentication within APIM Instance through portal.

I also creates AAD entry for APIM instance.

I am able to generate jwt bearer token as well through APIM developer legacy portal.

But how can I generate JWT token to call APIM methods from C# application.

I want to call APIM methods 
 using OAUTH2.0 JWT token from C# application .

How can I do that.

Pls provide samples if any.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to perform the following steps:

1) Create application inside azure ad 
2) Go to your APIM => Access control (IAM) Tab 
3) Add the created application above (permission is required to do this in APIM) 
4) Now you should be able to see Azure AD application in APIM Access control (IAM) Tab

Then you should be able to get the access token from your Azure AD, using the client id and client secret

```
public class myServiceCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials{
   private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; } 
   public override void InitializeServiceClient<T>(ServiceClient<T> client)
   {
      var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}");
      var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "xxxxx-xxxx-xx-xxxx-xxx", clientSecret: "{clientSecret}");
     var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);

    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
    }
    AuthenticationToken = result.AccessToken;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm getting jwt token now with above code, but throwing 401 unauthorized issue.  what is the value we need to use for <Validate-jwt > in inbound policies of APIM. Earlier, I have used   <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/... for <Validate-jwt>

Comment: I have created a new app ad for apim and used client id and secret in above code.I have also added new app ad under Access Control(IAM)  in APIM. Is there anything else I need to configure in APIM?  Do I need to configure OAUTH2.0 in APIM instance? What should be the validate-jwt policy values

Comment: i think the best option is if you reference to the documentation, because it will depend on your approach (if you use the jwt token via query string or via header) and also additional options that you need to consider. Have a look to this link and let me know if you have any problems - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT